# Reverse digits in number using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am new to C and I am trying to use recursion to reverse the digits in an integer (for example, 123 becomes 321). I also need to print the result using a void function called reverseDigits. The function successfully reverses the numbers, my problem is that when I try to print the results, it will print it multiple times. For example instead of printing just "321" it prints "321 321 321". I've noticed it prints the result as many digits are in the number. "12" outputs "21 21", "123" outputs "321 321 321" and so on. I cannot figure out what is causing this to happen. I just need it to print once. What is causing this to happen?
reverseDigits(123) in the main function is there just for the purpose of seeing what the results would be if that number was entered, it will not be in the final program. (Not sure if that is relevant or not).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse=0;
void reverseDigits(int number){
    int remainder;
    if (number!=0){
    remainder = number % 10;
    reverse = (reverse*10)+remainder;
    reverseDigits(number/10);
    printf("%i ",reverse);
    }
}

int main() {
reverseDigits(123);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use [the `div()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/div.html) to find the quotient and remainder in a single operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have `printf("%i ",reverse);` you will print for every layer of your recursion. If you recurse 3 times (ie for the 3 digit number) you will print 3 times. You should only print at the bottom of your recursion:

```
if (number!=0){
     ...
} else {
    printf("%i ",reverse);
}
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/5hzh9v)

*Little side note: Use a debugger next time. It makes it a lot easier to figure out why small programs are not working.*